# encodeURI in ajax url not working in case of & in parameter value

Tags: html, url, urlencode

i want to call an ajax function  and for encoding the URL parameters am using the default encodeURI method in java scrit and its working fine.

Now suppose am having a parameter value something like `a&b`. In this case even if i had done the URL encoding for this parameter it will not work, since an additional `&` will be append to the URI and this make the URI to brake there.

So how can i avoid this situation.?

Comment: got it...replace & with %26 which is the standard encoding for that character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved ..I Just replace `&` with `%26`, which is a standard encoding for that character